# What is causing this segfault in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, segmentation-fault

**Background:** Because Go's inbuilt JSON marshaller doesn't check for zero values when given the `omitempty` flag, we're trying using `*time.Time` rather than `time.Time` in structs that need to be marshalled cleanly to JSON. The problem with this is obviously we need to be very careful to always check it is not nil when using it. One thing we did notice was in a function that sets a creation time on the encompassing struct, when we checked the JSON in the database all of the times were exactly the same, down to the nanosecond.

To check whether this was something to do with the pointer or just because the system was performing very well, I made [this test](https://play.golang.org/p/Fq_3984pZ4):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Timekeeper struct {
    myTime *time.Time
}

func main() {

    t := make([]Timekeeper, 100)
    var now time.Time
    for _, v := range t {
        now = time.Now()
        v.myTime = &now
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

    for i, times := range t {
        fmt.Printf("Timekeeper %s time: %s.", i, times.myTime.Format(time.RFC3339Nano))
    }

}
```

but it keeps producing this panic:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0x20314]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x112c00, 0x1040a038)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x720
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox675251439/main.go:23 +0x314

Program exited.
```

I'm assuming this is *something* to do with the pointer being constantly reassigned to, but I've got a mental block going on and I can't figure out exactly what the issue is. Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Comment: In addition to what Ainar-G said: all pointers are equal and point the same variable. You should really get your logic straight.

Comment: Initially `now` was declared inside the loop, so that would be an entirely different pointer yes? I moved it outside while trying other ways, but didn't realise the issue was with the loop copying the value it was working with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your loop you copy every `Timekeeper` value. Do this instead:

```
for i := range t {
    now = time.Now()
    t[i].myTime = &now
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a mistake I keep making, then fixing, then making again a month later. Annoyingly I can't post a fixed version because https://play.golang.org thinks it's 10/11/09.